# What is the colon in an enum class declaration?

Tags: c++

I just found this weird piece of code in the `align_val_t` definition of Visual Studio 2019's standard library:

```
namespace std
{
    enum class align_val_t : size_t {};
}
```

What does the colon mean?

```
enum class align_val_t : size_t {};
//                     ^
//                 this thing
```

Comment: What specifically about this declaration you don't understand? Where do you see anything here that's related to "pointers"?

Comment: There is no "pointer" in the code you have shown. Just an empty `enum class`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/align_val_t

Comment: I meant two points, oops

Comment: It's called colon.

Comment: This specifies the enum's size. This is new in C++11. For more information, see any textbook that covers C++11.

Comment: It specifies the underlying type for the enum.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik its like you wanted to make an answer template, just replace c++11 with the standard of choice an voila, you "answer" the question.

Comment: I actually already have a couple of templates that I use frequently, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Open your C++ book and turn to the page about scoped enums. This is simply part of the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

The `enum Name : UnderlyingType {}` syntax defines an enum that is said to be *fixed*, with an *explicitly specified underlying type*. From [[dcl.enum]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#5):

> Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other types. Each enumeration also has an *underlying type*. **The underlying type can be explicitly specified using an [*enum-base*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.enum#nt:enum-base)**. For a scoped enumeration type, the underlying type is `int` if it is not explicitly specified. In both of these cases, the underlying type is said to be *fixed*.  [...]

---

> ```
> enum class align_val_t : size_t {};
> //                     ^
> //                 this thing
> ```

In this particular example, an enum named [`align_val_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/align_val_t) is defined (in the `std` namespace) as *fixed* with explicitly specified underlying type `size_t` ([`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), to be precise).

---

#### Scoped and unscoped enumerations & underlying types

```
// Unscoped enumeration; [enum Name {}]
// - underlying type not fixed.
enum UnscopedUnfixed { a, b };
auto uu_a = a;

// Scoped enumeration; [enum class Name {} / enum struct Name {}]
// - underlying type implicitly fixed to int.
enum class ScopedImplicitlyFixed { c, d };
auto sif_c = ScopedImplicitlyFixed::c;

// Scoped enumeration; [enum class Name : TYPE {} / enum struct Name : TYPE {}]
// - underlying type explicitly fixed.
enum class ScopedExplicitlyFixed : unsigned int { e, f };
auto sef_e = ScopedExplicitlyFixed::e;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> enum class align_val_t /*HERE----->*/:/*<------HERE*/ size_t {};
> ```

That colon is (an optional) part of the syntax of an enum (class) definition. It separates the name of the enum (class) and the underlying type.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, this is part of the syntax of [enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations)s, for which you can (but don't have to) specify the underlying type.

It's saying that every member of the `enum` has the type `std::size_t`; exactly that type, nothing else. In the olden days, it wasn't always quite so clear what the type would be, at least not by simply looking at the code.

Comment: _"it wasn't always quite so clear what the type would be, at least not by simply looking at the code"_ - not just unclear (and still the case in modern C++): unscoped enumerations without explicit underlying types are non-fixed, which has been a nefarious cause of bugs when combined with the generally evil pattern of casting integer type values to unscoped non-fixed enums. The width of the underlying type of such an enum is only guaranteed to be modulo 2 of the value of the largest individual enumerator, and casting even a small byte-sized integer to such an enum results in

Comment: ... undefined behaviour (as of modern C++; used to be unspecified behaviour, but this was a defect, iirc) if the underlying storage of the target enum cannot hold the integer value. E.g. casting the value 3 to an unscoped non-fixed enum of two enumerators could actually lead to UB.

Comment: @dfri: Exactly.